# CodeIgniter: when page reloads, It takes an old session_id stored in session cookie.

Tags: php, codeigniter, session-cookies

I have an codeigniter/php website and flex application.

I am logging with username "jhon" and do all the things, and getting logout.

Then If I logs in as a user "bob" from website, I am setting a new session datas like username, userId , firstName etc in codeigniter session. and also I have just noted down the codeIgniter session_id.

and then redirecting user to flex application, when user "bob" comes back to the website from app, by default codeigniter takes a session_id from session-cookie, which is different than which I seen before redirecting "bob" to flex application.

and I noticed that this changed session_id is belongs to the user "jhon".

I am not using `$this->session->sess_destroy();` at logout, just unsetting all session data with the use of `unset_userdata()`

Below is the my config.php setting for session and cookie.

```
config['sess_cookie_name']      = 'cisession';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;


$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "";
$config['cookie_path']      = "/";
```

I am using database and table "ci_sessions" to store sessions. I mostly seen this problem in chrome browser and that also exact after system restart.

Means I am logging in as a "jhon", doing this and that...
Logging out..
Restrating my system..
again logging in as "bob", redirected to flex app..
coming back to codeigniter website.
I am getting logged in as "jhon"....

What is the problem?

Comment: If you want to automaticly doing that, without destroy all session data(which you may save something important), you can change `$config['sess_time_to_update']` to more shorter frequency and that will regenerate new id by value you has declare.

Comment: Actually My problem is, at jhon's login it is storing session '8346365934644' in cookies. I am not logging out but restarting browser, again logging in with 'bob', new session_id is generated '23823623492', but when I refresh page after 45 secs, it again get session_id '8346365934644'. from where? I don't know!. I think it is matching up ip-address, and user-agent data from 'ci_sessions' table.

Comment: `from where? I don't know!. I think it is matching up ip-address, and user-agent data from 'ci_sessions' table.` Submit it as a bug, if that really happen, because it shouldnt. The session class should update data in the database too as the actual cookie being updated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't use `$this->session->sess_destroy();` which [kills the session_id from the database](https://bitbucket.org/ellislab/codeigniter/src/252e9c8091cc/system/libraries/Session.php#cl-389).

Comment: But If some user is not logging out, closing the browser, and restarting system, then also this problem arises. let's have example, 'jhon' is logged in, not doing logout, closing the browser, and system... 'bob' comes up early morning, starting the sysetm, logged in to website, at that time new 'session_id' is getting generated, but after it comes from application back to website withing 30secs, codeigniter automatically takes session_id of 'jhon'.